# Excel 2007/2010 color scale conditional formatting based on formula

Tags: excel, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

Suppose I have the following table structure (A1:C3)

```
     A   B   C
1    H1  H2  H3
2    1   1   3
3    4   5   4
```

How can I apply a conditional formatting with the following conditions:

- Only the header cells (H1,H2,H3) are colored
- The coloring scheme is 2 or 3-color-scale
- The values used for computing the color should be A2/A3, B2/B3, C2/C3 (range is 0-1)

*Note: I'm not looking for a VBA solution, as I can make my own, but if you have some crazy 1 liner please tell :)*
*Note: I don't want to apply a lot of rules like `if x<0.3 red`, `if 0.3<x<0.6 orange` etc.*

Is there any clean solution for this?
Can a 3-color-scale be applied based on the value of a formula?

Comment: Are you asking whether it is possible to have conditional formatting without having conditions?

Comment: No, I'm asking if conditional formatting, using a 3-color-scale style is possible in conjunction with formulas; so instead of coloring based on the cell value, I could color based on the result of a formula involving other cells

Comment: I'll also accept a VBA script, if it's a really short one. I'm looking for a quick and dirty hack :) I know how to write a long solution iterating over all headers, computing the color ... but just for fun I want to see some clever solutions :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something nifty that unfortunately doesn't exist. I just see the two options.

You can either do conditional formatting with three conditions, or even just two if you want to use the default cell color as one of the three (e.g. Formula Is =(A2/A3)<0.3, Formula Is =(A2/A3)<0.6, or whatever you want your threshold values to be). You can apply this fomatting manually on one header cell in Excel, and copy it across to all headers; or apply it through VBA.

Or you can color the headers in VBA, and place a button on your sheet that calls the code to update the colors.

```
With Range("A1")
    For i = 1 To 3
        colorscale = .Cells(2, i).Value / .Cells(3, i).Value
        .Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = _
            RGB(colorscale * 255, colorscale * 255, _
            colorscale * 255) ' for example. Or pick your colors otherwise.
    Next i
End With
```

Sounds to me like the first option (conditional formatting) is better suited, because it will update the colors automatically based on the cell values. I have to admit, though, I don't quite see why you're looking for something "cleaner" than this, because it's actually a really simple solution. Do two conditions constitute "a lot of rules"? Not by any stretch of the English language...

Comment: It's not just two rules. I want to see the full gradient from red-yellow-green based on the result, which can be any subunit fraction. I was hoping to somehow be able to compute this gradient using some direct API, but I don't think there is something to do that.

Comment: Aha. By "2 or 3-color-scale" I thought you meant a scale with two or three possible colors. You just meant RGB.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an adaptation of Jean-François Corbett's code that takes the color from a red-yellow-green gradient:

```
With Range("A1")
    For i = 1 To 3
        ColorScale = .Cells(2, i).Value / .Cells(3, i).Value
        If ColorScale < 0.5 Then
            red = 255
            green = ColorScale * 2 * 255
        Else
            red = (1 - ColorScale) * 2 * 255
            green = 255
        End If

        .Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = RGB(red, green, 0)
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Does Excel 2007 accept any arbitrary cell color? Or is it still restricted to a 40-color palette like Excel 2003? (I'm still using 2003.)

Comment: I believe so, I just ran a loop from 1 to 100 and got a nice gradient. (in Excel 2010 at least, I don't have 2007 at home)

Comment: Nice. Palettes are so three decades ago!